# Move SVG Elements with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am dynamically placing svg text elements on a template wrapped in a svg group. I need the user to have the functionality of moving each element individually with the keyboard arrow keys after it is clicked/focused. My current code below has some issue. 1. The arrow key will move the element once and then I get the error: Unexpected value translate(NaN,undefined) parsing transform attribute. 2. If there is more than one element on the canvas, it will move them all and not just the element that was clicked on. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(".svg-canvas").on("click",".selectable",function() {
    var el = $(this).attr("id");
    keymove(el);                
});

function keymove(el) {
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {//right            
        console.log('right');
        var xforms = $("#" + el).attr("transform");
        var parts  = /\((.*)\)$/.exec(xforms);
        var parts2 = parts[1].split(",");
        var x = parts2[4];
        var y = parts2[5];          
        var tx = (++x);
        $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ tx + ',' + y +')'});                      
    }else if(e.keyCode == 37) {//left
        console.log('left');
        var xforms = $("#" + el).attr("transform");
        var parts  = /\((.*)\)$/.exec(xforms);
        var parts2 = parts[1].split(",");
        var x = parts2[4];
        var y = parts2[5];
        var tx = (--x);
        $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ tx + ',' + y +')'});
    }else if(e.keyCode == 38) {//up
        console.log('up');
        var xforms = $("#" + el).attr("transform");
        var parts  = /\((.*)\)$/.exec(xforms);
        var parts2 = parts[1].split(",");
        var x = parts2[4];
        var y = parts2[5];
        var ty = (--y);
        $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ x + ',' + ty +')'});
    }else if(e.keyCode == 40) {//down
        console.log('down');
        var xforms = $("#" + el).attr("transform");
        var parts  = /\((.*)\)$/.exec(xforms);
        var parts2 = parts[1].split(",");
        var x = parts2[4];
        var y = parts2[5];
        var ty = (++y);
        $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ x + ',' + ty +')'});
    }else{
        return; 
    }               
});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: Never used fiddle before so I hope this is a help to you. https://jsfiddle.net/svotv5g2/8/

Comment: How horrible. Use the SVG DOM to parse the transform arguments rather than rolling your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set the `transform` property to `translate..` in here: `$("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ tx + ',' + y +')'});`, you can't get the property in `matrix` mode.

So when you are trying to do: `var xforms = $("#" + el).attr("transform");` you get `translate(236,205)` so the parsing is wrong.

The solution is to set the `transform` values in `matrix` combination too, so you will can read it in the next action.

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean. Do you mean when I update     $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate('+ tx + ',' + y +')'}); it should be     $("#" + el).attr({transform:'translate(1,0,0,1,' + tx + ',' + y +')'}); instead?

Comment: I believe I understand now after looking at it. I have updated my fiddle to reflect the change. https://jsfiddle.net/svotv5g2/14/ Now the next issue is, if you click on one element it moves just fine but If you click on another, both or all elements begin to move.

Comment: You add a window keydown event every time the user clicks an element. Remove the event on keymove function ( $(window).off("keydown"); ) or add only one event to the window.

Comment: Could you update my fiddle to reflect your code change suggested? https://jsfiddle.net/svotv5g2/18/

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Look at the line 9 in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/svotv5g2/19/

Comment: For other hand, if you want to use regular expressions, your code could be like this:
var parts  = /^matrix\(.+?([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)\)$/;
var x = xforms.replace(parts, "$1");
var y = xforms.replace(parts, "$2");

Comment: Thanks again for your help and suggestions.